# SSH with remote command and keep session alive

Tags: command-line, server, bash, ssh, environment-variables

I want to ssh to remote machine while setting some environment variable.

Let's just say, I don't want to make any changes on remote machine.

I want to do something like:

```bsh
ssh remote-server "NAME=$NAME;"
```

The problems with the above command are:

1. I want to keep the session alive. But it closes as soon as the command exits.

   I can do:

   ```bsh
   ssh -t remote-server "NAME=$NAME; bash"
   ```

   But then in the resulting session, `NAME` is undefined.
2. I also want `/etc/motd` to print.

   I can also do:

   ```bsh
   ssh -t remote-server "cat /etc/motd;NAME=$NAME; bash"
   ```

   which works (the first issue still remains), but if there are more elegant solutions, please do tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***TL;DR:* `ssh -t remote-server "NAME=$NAME bash"` (no `;` before `bash`), but consider other ways.**

*Before using anything in this answer, please look at the **Security Implications** section below.*

When you run `ssh` and give it a specific command to run, it runs the command using whatever shell is configured as the remote user's login shell. The effect therefore depends on what shell that is, but the most popular shells are Bourne-style shells. This includes `sh`, `bash`, `zsh`, `ksh`, and various others. It does not include `tcsh` and `fish`, which are probably the most popular non-Bourne-style shells.

Your goal here is to run `bash` on the remote machine with a new or changed environment variable, and the shell on your local machine (where you're running the `ssh` command) may be `bash`, but the remote user's login shell is not necessarily `bash`. That shell is listed in the remote machine's password database; it is included in the record retrieved by running `getent passwd user` on the remote machine, where *`user`* is the remote username.

In a Bourne-style shell, environment variables are shell variables, but not all shell variables are environment variables. When you run something of the form `NAME=value` as a *full command*, there are three cases:

- If `NAME` is already an environment variable, it is also a shell variable, and assigning to that shell variable also updates the environment variable.
- If `NAME` is not an environment variable, but it exists as a shell variable, assigning to that shell variable updates its value but does not cause it to become an environment variable.
- If `NAME` is unset (i.e., there is no variable by that name), then assigning to it creates a shell variable with the specified value, but this shell variable is not an environment variable.

To cause a shell variable to be an environment variable for all subsequent commands, you *export* it with the `export` builtin:

```bash
export NAME
```

The `export` builtin also supports assignment syntax, for giving the variable a new value--or its initial value--and exporting it at the same time:

```
export NAME=value
```

So one option you have is:

```bash
ssh -t remote-server "export NAME=$NAME; bash"
```

That differs from your code by the addition of `export`.

But Bourne-style shells also support setting an environment variable with a specific value *just for the duration of a single command*. This is what assignments at the beginning of a command do. So you can use this instead:

```bash
ssh -t remote-server "NAME=$NAME bash"
```

That differs from your code by the removal of the `;` that caused the assignment to be taken as a command of its own.

To cover non-Bourne-style login shells, you can use whatever syntax that shell expects. To *attempt* to cover as many shells as possible with the same syntax, you can use the `env` command to set the variable and run the command. `env` supports `NAME=value` syntax even if the shell running it does not.

```bash
ssh -t remote-server "env NAME=$NAME bash"
```

Presuming your MOTD is *normally* displayed, the best way to get it to display--and to achieve other effects you may want--is to tell `bash` to behave as a login shell. One way to do that is to pass the `--login` flag to `bash`:

```
ssh -t remote-server "export NAME=$NAME; bash --login"
```

```bash
ssh -t remote-server "NAME=$NAME bash --login"
```

```bash
ssh -t remote-server "env NAME=$NAME bash --login"
```

But if you prefer you can `cat` the file before running your command, just as you were doing.

### Security Implications

As you know (and intend), your own shell expands `$NAME` before running `ssh`. If it contains characters that are treated specially by the *remote* shell, you have a problem. This means it has the disadvantage of not working under some common simple cases, like if that value contains spaces. It also means you can accidentally use values that have effects you don't expect. **As a corollary, this is only safe if you always control the contents of that variable.** If you're setting the value yourself, that's okay. If the value may be set by someone else, that person can cause *any command they want* to run on the remote machine.

You might try to control for this by writing `NAME='$NAME'` instead. This is good for cases where you're deliberately doing something simple, like when `$NAME` may contain spaces. But it does not cover all cases, and **as far as security is concerned it unfortunately provides no mitigation at all**. A variable may contain the `'` character. (If you don't know what shell is configured as the remote user's login shell, there is also the issue that non-Bourne-style shells have different quoting rules.)

Note that this does not affect the case of running the code `x="$y"` in a shell where `x` and `y` are variables and you want to assign the value of `y` to `x`. That works and is safe. But that's not what you're doing here. Instead, you're pasting the value of `NAME`, whatever it is, into code that the remote machine runs. When you don't fully control that value, there is no generally safe way to do that.

**If you *do* control the value and you know what you're doing, then it is okay.** Otherwise, one approach is to attempt to modify its value into something that is fully and safely quoted and to insert that into the command that runs on the remote machine. This is difficult to get right, but you can write code to replace each `'` character with the sequence `'\''`. More complex quoting situations than the one here can be attempted with the `%q` format specifier of the `printf` command.

**It's even better to avoid this entirely and use a separate mechanism** to pass the variable through to the remote system. Instead of any of the commands suggested above, you should consider:

```bash
ssh -o SendEnv=NAME
```

However, this doesn't meet your requirement to avoid modifying files stored on the remote machine. The remote server must be configured to allow the environment variable `NAME` to be passed through. [That approach, and others like `PermitUserEnvironment`, require editing `/etc/sshd_config` on the remote machine.](https://superuser.com/questions/163167/when-sshing-how-can-i-set-an-environment-variable-on-the-server-that-changes-f) But if you goal is simply to avoid editing files on the remote machine in a way that embeds *any specific value* of the `NAME` environment variable in any file on it, then you should use `SendEnv`.

Comment: So instead of opening bash after ssh, what if we want to open the user configured default shell.